# Best Approach: Mutliple content place holders in MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am converting an ASP.Net web forms project to MVC3. The master page contains multiple content place holders at different locations.

I replaced the first content place holder with `@RenderBody()` but I am confused with what to do of the second one.

One approach might be to separate views and place a `@Html.RenderAction()` for each content place holder method. Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Razor has got `sections` understanding in place of asp.net webforms ContentPlaceHolders. Take a look at [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/30/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor.aspx) introductionary link.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This link could be a better reading for sections (http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/30/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor.aspx). Please include this in your answer for future questions...

Comment: Sorry, I just corrected it. It was the copy paste typo by me :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use sections. For example, to have a section for scripts, in the head tag of the layout.cshtml, you can specifiy

```
<head>    
<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>    
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />    
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>    
@RenderSection("scripts", false);
</head>
```

Inside of any view, you can now add a scripts section to inject your scripts:

```
@section scripts{    
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/myscript.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
}
```

the "false" param tells MVC to render the section if exists on the child page or do nothing if no call

Comment: +1 you provided the right answer, but I chose @archil's one as the answer because he replied first...

Comment: @Naveed Butt: NP. What's matter is that you solved your problem ;)